# Count number of nodes within range inside Binary Search Tree in O(LogN)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a BST and two integers 'a' and 'b' (a < b), how can we find the number of nodes such that , a < node value < b, in O(log n)?

I know one can easily find the position of a and b in LogN time, but how to count the nodes in between without doing a traversal, which is O(n)?

Comment: Why don't you simply let each node maintain a variable with the number of nodes in the subtree below it?

Comment: You can't count N things in LogN time -- you have to have the information already created from when you built the tree.

Comment: augmented search trees?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In each node of your Binary Search Tree, also keep count of the number of values in the tree that are lesser than its value (or, for a different tree design mentioned in the footnote below, the nodes in its left subtree).

Now, first find the node containing the value `a`. Get the count of values lesser than `a` which has been stored in this node. This step is Log(n).

Now find the node containing the value `b`. Get the count of values lesser than `b` which are stored in this node. This step is also Log(n).

Subtract the two counts and you have the number of nodes between `a` and `b`. Total complexity of this search is 2*Log(n) = O(Log(n)).

---

<sub>*See [this video](https://youtu.be/zksIj9O8_jc?t=22m15s). The professor explains your question here by using Splay Trees.*</sub>

Comment: "The nodes in Splay Trees keep count of element in the left and right subtree automatically, by design" That's news to me... The common formulation of [splay trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree) does not have that property AFAIK

Comment: @NiklasB.: I studied Splay Trees from [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=G5QIXywcJlY). This is how he described the Splay Tree. I agree that Wikipedia page doesn't give that definition.

Comment: @NiklasB.: To keep the answer general and correct, I have updated it too.

Comment: Could you give me the time where this is covered in the youtube video? Basically your answer now suggests using a splay tree with subtree size augmentation, but then obviously you have exactly the bookkeeping information that you said this would avoid?

Comment: @NiklasB.: Not only he describes the Splay Tree that way, he has even explained how to use those properties of Splay Tree to find nodes between some _a_ and _b_.

Comment: @NiklasB.: He didn't cover it in the video I linked you to earlier, it's actually in [this one](https://youtu.be/zksIj9O8_jc?t=22m15s). Also, you were right, this is not a general design of Splay Trees. He mentions that this is extra information in the node. It'd been a long time since I studied it, so my memory failed me about it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

- Start checking from the root node
- If Node falls within range, then increase it by 1 and check in left and right child recursively
- If Node is not within range, then check the values with range. If range values are less than root, then definitely possible scenarios are left subtree. Else check in right subtree

  Here is the sample code. Hope it clears.

  ```
  if (node == null) {
      return 0;
  } else if (node.data == x && node.data == y) {
      return 1;
  } else if (node.data >= x && node.data <= y) {
      return 1 + nodesWithInRange(node.left, x, y) + nodesWithInRange(node.right, x, y);
  } else if (node.data > x && node.data > y) {
      return nodesWithInRange(node.left, x, y);
  } else {
      return nodesWithInRange(node.right, x, y);
  }
  ```

Time Complexity :- O(logn)+ O(K)

K is the number of elements between x and y.

It's not very ideal but good in case you would not like to modify the Binary Tree nodes definition.

Comment: Not a solution (yet). If a node is outside the range, you return 0, ignoring that the range belongs in its left or right sub-tree. Once you accommodate for that, your answer is similar to [FallAndLearn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37010151/3789665), including hand-waving how this is `in O(log n)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks. Good  point ! I have updated my solution. Also put complexity details.

Answer (score 1):

store the inorder traversal of BST in array( it will be sorted). Searching 'a' and 'b' will take log(n) time and get their index and take the difference. this will give the number of node in range 'a' to 'b'.

space complexity O(n)

Comment: Inorder traversal will take O(n) time. You are not counting that.

Comment: Yes! this will built once but the query result will always be O(log n)

Answer (score -1):

Idea is simple.

1. Traverse the BST starting from root.
2. For every node check if it lies in range.
   If it lies in range then count++. And recur for both of its children.
3. If current node is smaller than low value of range, then recur for right child, else recur for left child.

Time complexity will be `O(height + number of nodes in range)`..

For your question that why it is not `O(n)`.

Because we are not traversing the whole tree that is the number of nodes in the tree. We are just traversing the required subtree according to the parent's data.

Pseudocode

```
int findCountInRange(Node root, int a, int b){

    if(root==null)
       return 0;
    if(root->data <= a && root->data >= b)
         return 1 + findCountInRange(root->left, a, b)+findCountInRange(root->right, a, b); 
    else if(root->data < low)
         return findCountInRange(root->right, a, b);
    else 
         return findCountInRange(root->left, a, b);

}
```

Comment: What if the query range covers all elements in the tree? then your algorithm is indeed Omega(n)

Comment: Correction. Complexity will be O(height + number of nodes in range).

Comment: what if a and b are the lowest and highest nodes in tree, respectively? am I missing some mathematical property that'd make exploring those nodes O(nlog)?

Comment: if a and b are the lowest and highest nodes. Then time complexity will be O(heigh+n), which can be written O(n).

Comment: I would appreciate writing the reason for downvoting. It would help all.

Comment: wasn't me :), but I assume its because your solution gives O(n) rather than O(logN).